# Impossible WHERE when ANDing several criteria

Tags: mysql, selection, criteria

I have a table named links which contains a column idl (PRIMARY) and three columns ide, idd and idv which are integers bound by a foreign key to corresponding tables entities, descriptors and values, each one containing a PRIMARY index on ide, idd, idv, respectively.
I want to select the entries corresponding to some criteria.

A query

```
    SELECT DISTINCT(l.ide)
    FROM links l 
    WHERE (idd = 34 AND idv = 60) OR (idd = 31 AND idv = 166)
```

works fine.
But the same query with AND doesn't give any result (I positively know that there should be a result).

When I ask for the explanation, I get the message 'Impossible QUERY'.

Thanks in advance for any clue.

**Edition:**
In my table, I have at least two rows (idl, ide, idd, idv):
    `232, 297, 31, 166`
and
    `235, 297, 34, 60`.

I want to select the ide 297.

I hope this will be clearer.

Comment: `idd` cann't be 34 **AND** 31 at the time time (for the same row). That's **impossible**. So what is your question?

Comment: If you know there should be a result, it means that you didn't express your idea correctly. Adding a little sample data and what is your expected result could help us understand what you want to do

Comment: "When I ask for the explanation " ???  how you ask  ??  who answer  to you??

Comment: @scaisEdge the OP is probably talking about the `EXPLAIN` mysql keyword here

Comment: Note that DISTINCT is not a function

Comment: I edited my question to give a small dataset.

Comment: Your query returns 297

Answer (score 0):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS links;

CREATE TABLE links
(ide INT NOT NULL
,idd INT NOT NULL
,idv INT NOT NULL
,PRIMARY KEY(ide,idd)
);

INSERT INTO links VALUES
(1,34,60),
(1,31,166);

SELECT * FROM links;
+-----+-----+-----+
| ide | idd | idv |
+-----+-----+-----+
|   1 |  34 |  60 |
|   1 |  31 | 166 |
+-----+-----+-----+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

SELECT ide FROM links WHERE (idd,idv) IN((34,60),(31,166)) GROUP BY ide HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;
+-----+
| ide |
+-----+
|   1 |
+-----+
```

Comment: I didn't know that the IN operator accepted such nested constructions. While testing, I noticed that if I delete the `HAVING COUNT` member, I get the same result as the OR query above.

Comment: If you get rid of the HAVING, you might as well get rid of the GROUP BY; it doesn't really make sense to have a GROUP BY clause with no aggregating functions.

Comment: More, I can't know what the value of the `HAVING COUNT` member will be. I can have a search with two, three and more criteria. The set of criteria is open. For instance, the descriptor can be the form of the head, the color of the hair, the color of the abdomen. My aim is to build an entomological matrix key, where the user selects the criteria he/she knows and ask for the resulting set.

Comment: You always know the value of count (more specifically, you always know the value of count(DISTINCT (idd,id)) . It's impossible for it to be otherwise.